# HTML5 and CSS3 Only

Tags: html, css, project

I was wondering if anybody knew of any websites that have different projects for learning HTML5 and CSS3. I don't want to learn Javascript just yet. I just want to see how good a website can be with only HTML5 and CSS3.

Any tutorials or projects that start from scratch and construct an impressive website would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend you to google it**.

But in my oponion [**w3schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/) is great for starters and [**Udemy**](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=html5%20css3) has many online courses.

Also you can visit these question:

- [Learning HTML5 and CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161661/learning-html5-and-css3)
- [HTML5 & CSS3 Fundamentals: Development for Absolute Beginners](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/html5-css3-fundamentals-development-for-absolute-beginners#?fbid=RVVg_iR_pyP)
- [Coding An HTML 5 Layout From Scratch](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/04/designing-a-html-5-layout-from-scratch/)

Also there are bunchs of video tutorials and e-books like:

- [learnr.pro](http://www.learnr.pro/search/query/?q=html5%20css3)
- [CSS3: The Missing Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00APOSIEQ)
- [HTML5 for Masterminds, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00570RJQ6)
- [Responsive Web Design with HTML5 and CSS3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007SVJA3M)

Comment: w3schools? I didn't really get on with that before hand as Google let me know some pretty big errors with it as a resource.

Comment: @abberto Try an ebook. and w3schools is a great beginner to intermediate resource.

Comment: I think I'm just skeptical as I used it previously and didn't get along with it. an ebook is a good idea. At the moment, I am still just learning things and have made [this](http://www.mrabbott.co.uk)

Comment: @abberto That's nice. Keep learning by doing. But try to read ebooks or any tutorial which has solid structured.

Comment: @abberto also this site is fine: https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=html5+css3

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to follow the course "Web Fundamentals" of this portal: [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/)

Comment: Ahhh Code Academy. I have used this before and had forgotten about it. I'll have to get back into that one I think. Then I can use my test development site to test new things